# HttpUrlReservation Failing with custom port

Tags: wix, wix3.10

When using the new module in WiX 3.10.1 to reserve a port, if I reserve on :8080, it works fine, but when trying to reserve on a different port, say :444, it fails.  running a full log of the installation from msiexec.exe, i'm getting the following that looks pertinent to the situation:

```
ExecFirewallExceptions:  Installing firewall exception2 xxx on port 444 , protocol 6
ExecFirewallExceptions:  Error 0x8000ffff: failed to set exception port
ExecFirewallExceptions:  Error 0x8000ffff: failed to create FwRule object
Action 15:49:57: WixRollbackHttpUrlReservationsInstall. Rolling back Windows HTTP Server configuration
Action 15:49:57: WixExecHttpUrlReservationsInstall. Configuring Windows HTTP Server
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Adding reservation for URL 'http://+:444 /' with SDDL 'D:(A;;0x10000000;;;S-1-1-0)'
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Error 0x80070057: Failed to add URL reservation: http://+:444 /, ACL: D:(A;;0x10000000;;;S-1-1-0)
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Error 0x80070057: Failed to add reservation for URL 'http://+:444 /' with SDDL 'D:(A;;0x10000000;;;S-1-1-0)'
CustomAction WixExecHttpUrlReservationsInstall returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 15:49:57: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 15:49:57: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Configuring Windows HTTP Server
Rollback: Rolling back Windows HTTP Server configuration
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Removing reservation for URL 'http://+:444 /'
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Error 0x80070057: Failed to remove URL reservation: http://+:444 /
ExecHttpUrlReservations:  Error 0x80070057: Failed to remove reservation for URL 'http://+:444 /'
CustomAction WixRollbackHttpUrlReservationsInstall returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
```

In my example on the ports, the msi installer is setup to install to :8080 by default, and there is a custom dialog which allows users to provide a custom port.  When they do, two things happen:

1. I update an app.config file and set the updated port information from the user
2. i try to use the `UrlReservation` and `FirewallException` tools from the wix toolset to do what is necessary to bring the application online.

This application hosts an owin self-hosted website, if that makes much difference.

my configuration is as follows to do this work:

```
  <Component Id="exe_Runtime" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="_exe_Runtime" KeyPath="yes" Source="..." />
    <File Id="_exe_Runtime_Config" Source="....config" />
    <util:XmlFile Id="SetConsolePort"
                  File="[#_exe_Runtime_Config]"
                  Action="setValue"
                  Name="value"
                  ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key=&quot;drey.configuration.consoleport&quot;[\]]"
                  Value="[CONSOLEPORT]" />

    <util:XmlFile Id="SetHordeDirectory"
                  File="[#_exe_Runtime_Config]"
                  Action="setValue"
                  Name="value"
                  ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key=&quot;WorkingDirectory&quot;[\]]"
                  Value="[FLDR_APPDATA]" />

    <!-- Opens the console port -->
    <http:UrlReservation Url="http://+:[CONSOLEPORT]/" HandleExisting="ignore">
      <http:UrlAce SecurityPrincipal="Everyone" Rights="all" />
    </http:UrlReservation>

    <!-- Opens the firewall for incoming connection(s) -->
    <fire:FirewallException Id="_exe_runtime_FWX1" 
                            Name="xxx" 
                            Port="[CONSOLEPORT]" 
                            Protocol="tcp"
                            IgnoreFailure="yes" 
                            Scope="any" 
                            Profile="all" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="_exe_runtime_ServiceInstall"
                    Name="S3Client"
                    DisplayName="xxxx"
                    ErrorControl="normal"
                    Start="auto"
                    Type="ownProcess"
                    Vital="yes" />

    <ServiceControl Id="_exe_runtime_ServiceControl"
                    Name="S3Client"
                    Start="install"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="uninstall"
                    Wait="yes" />
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because of the space in the port (`http://+:444 /`).  It would be hard for WiX to automatically fix this.

Comment: that was quick.  off to find out if i can trim spaces in custom fields, unless you have a suggestion on this?